# How to achieve a simplified interface for C++ function template?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have function templates with two arguments, but the second argument is dictated by the first, and I would like to avoid writing both arguments when I call the function - that will help prevent mistakes and also be cleaner. I am looking for design advice or language features that will let me do this.

Given:

```
/* E1 and E2 always correspond to T1, and E3 always corresponds to T2 */
enum class MyEnum { E1,E2,E3 };
struct T1 { };
struct T2 { };

/* definition */
template <MyEnum E, typename T>
T* Function() { /* do something */ }

/* explicit specializations */
template T1* Function<MyEnum::E1, T1>();
template T1* Function<MyEnum::E2, T1>();
template T2* Function<MyEnum::E3, T2>();
```

How can I achieve a calling convention that does not require the caller to specify argument 2?

```
// I want to avoid this:
T1 * t1 = Function<MyEnum::E1, T1> ();
    
// I *do* (ideally) want this:
// I thought template argument deduction might work, but compilation fails
T1* t1 = Function<MyEnum::E1>();
```

Comment: You can write an indirection struct that maps `MyEnum::EX` to appropriate class. And default `T` to whatever the indirection points to.

Comment: How about a simple `auto` return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` might be a good way:

```
template <MyEnum E>
auto Function()
{
    if constexpr (E == MyEnum::E3) {
        /* do something and return a T2* */
    } else {
        /* do something and return a T1* */
    }
}
```

Else, you can create custom "traits":

```
#if 1 // In your case a simple `std::conditional` does the job

template <MyEnum E>
using ret_type_t = std::conditional_t<MyEnum::E3 == E, T2*, T1*>;

#else // The more classical way

template <MyEnum E>
struct ret_type
{
    using type = T1*;
};
template <>
struct ret_type<MyEnum::E3>
{
    using type = T2*;
};
template <MyEnum E> using ret_type_t = typename ret_type<E>::type;

#endif
```

And then

```
template <MyEnum E>
ret_type_t<E> Function() { /* do something */ }
```

Comment: This works great, thank you! If you don't mind - how did you become so proficient in C++? Do you recommend particular books / did you study the language systematically, or is this simply experience?

Comment: I studied in (3-years) school specialized in programming (not just the last year). I got 15+ years of professional experience now, did/participate on open project. answer to SO question (and so sometime have to investigate, and also learn for others).

Comment: Thanks again, much obliged.